# tuple becomes empty after one iteration of for loop

Tags: for-loop, tuples

I have a problem with this code. Even though the `if` conditional is for equivalence of the tuple object, after the second iteration of `for` loop, the whole parent tuple becomes empty, and I receive error:

```py
IndexError: list index out of range
```

```py
tup = ((1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 3), (1, 2))


def remove_dup(event, schedule):
    for i in schedule: 
        if i == event:
            schedule = tuple((list(schedule[1:])).remove(i))
    return schedule


remove_dup((1, 2), tup)  # should remove (1, 2) of index 3
```

I was hoping that the for loop would remove the last child tuple `(1, 2)`, as it is equivalent to the event.

Comment: One problem that I see is `list(schedule[1:])).remove(i)` returns `None`. You have to save `list(schedule[1:]))` first and then use the `remove` method on that object. After that, you can convert it back to `tuple`. But then you will need to check your code because it will lead to more errors.

Comment: sflr, Thank you for the response have a good day!